# For docker volume plugins what's the difference between "global" and "local" scope?

Tags: docker

The Capabilities endpoint of a Docker Volume Plugin indicates that the scope can be `global` or `local`.  However I still do not understand the difference especially if you're a plugin author.

I am thinking that "local" would be needed if you have to access a node's resource during `Create` and a global one can figure out everything from the options.

Answer (score 1):

**Volume Scopes:**

Supported scopes are **global** and **local**. Any other value in Scope will be ignored, and local is used. Scope allows **cluster managers** to handle the volume in different ways. For instance, a scope of global, signals to the cluster manager that it only needs to **create the volume once** instead of on each Docker host. More capabilities may be added in the future.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_volume/#volumedrivercapabilities)

If you are developing a plugin to handle shared storage for clustered environments, you probably should use global for a volume that can be used on different docker-hosts.

Example:
[Rexray](https://github.com/rexray/rexray)

Comment: Yes I can read the docker documentation about it but it does not explain what happens .  WHen should the plugin author decide to use local or global?

Comment: I tried doing both "global" and "local" I don't really see any difference in the outcome.  Although most of the volume plugins I see that use `mount` tend to use `local`